# How to sort values in object literal using ternary operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, rest, api, ecmascript-6

hi guys I am trying to sort the rest api values and there are some issues. the value is only displayed when the value, for example "price" in range of 100-150$ is only equal to 150 not less. i cannot find out why. here is the code below:

```
submitBtn.click(function(){
    var priceInputVal = priceInput.val(); 
    // var output = priceInputVal + '||' + priceList.priceMin[priceInputVal] + ' - ' + priceList.priceMax[priceInputVal];
    $.getJSON('http://didubeplaza.local/wp-json/wp/v2/office-list', function(office_data){

        outputCont.html(`
            ${office_data.map(item => `
                ${item.office_area[0] <= areaList.areaMax[priceInputVal]
                 ? `${item.office_area[0] >= areaList.areaMin[priceInputVal]
                        ? `${item.office_price[0] <= priceList.priceMax[priceInputVal]
                                ? `${item.office_price[0] >= priceList.priceMin[priceInputVal]
                                        ? `<div class="col-sm-4 mb-3">
                                                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                                      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://www.decorouscontract.com/wp-content/uploads/Vitra-Workspace-by-Pernilla-Ohrstedt_dezeen_468_3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                                                      <div class="card-body">
                                                        <h5 class="card-title">${item.title.rendered}</h5>
                                                      </div>
                                                      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                                        <li class="list-group-item">Area: ${item.office_area}</li>
                                                        <li class="list-group-item">Price: ${item.office_price}</li>
                                                        <li class="list-group-item">Status: </li>
                                                      </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>`
                                        : `<p>min price too small</p>`
                                    }`
                                : `<p>max price too high</p>`
                            }`
                        : `<p>min area too little</p>`
                    }`
                 : `<p>arrea max too high</p>`
                }

                `).join('')}    
        `);
    });
});

});
```

Comment: What is the value of `priceList.priceMin[priceInputVal]`?

Comment: i have an object priceList and inside of it is priceMin and priceMax and based on <select></select> input value i choose one from priceMax and priceMin

Comment: Is `item.office_price` an array? I've noticed you output it as: `Price: ${item.office_price}` without `[0]`, but you use 0 index in ternary operator's condition.

Comment: yes it is i added custom field values to rest api for wordpress and it displayed as an array with only one value.

Comment: Are you sure the values you compare are numbers and not strings?

Comment: Can you give me an advice on how to make sure they are?

Comment: First of all before `outputCont.html` you can declare a variable like `var office_price = parseInt(item.office_price[0]);`. And the same for `areaList.areaMax[priceInputVal]`: `var area_max = parseInt(areaList.areaMax[priceInputVal]);`. In doing so you also move repeated computations out of mapper function which make overall code more effective and readable.

Comment: Then I would appeal to one of the principles of Python programming language: flat is better than nested. Ternaries inside ternaries is hard to understand and debug. I would advice to flatten the algorithm. Though it looks like proper functional-style spirit, template strings inside template strings drive me bananas while reading.

Comment: yes i think flatter would be better but i need to compare value sequentely, otherwise i don't think it'll work

Comment: maybe i could define function outside and use normal if  and else statements and then call it inside template literal

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of flatten version:

```
const office_area = parseFloat(item.office_area[0]);
const office_price = parseInt(item.office_price[0]);
const max_area = parseFloat(areaList.areaMax[priceInputVal]);
const min_area = parseFloat(areaList.areaMin[priceInputVal]);
const max_price = parseInt(priceList.priceMax[priceInputVal]);
const min_price = parseInt(priceList.priceMin[priceInputVal]);
outputCont.html(
  office_data.map(item => {
    if (office_area > max_area) {
      return "area is too large";
    }
    if (office_area < min_area) {
      return "area is too small";
    }
    if (office_price > max_price) {
      return "price is too high";
    }
    if (office_price < min_price) {
      return "price is too low";
    }
    return `
      <div class="col-sm-4 mb-3">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="http://www.decorouscontract.com/wp-content/uploads/Vitra-Workspace-by-Pernilla-Ohrstedt_dezeen_468_3.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">${item.title.rendered}</h5>
          </div>
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item">Area: ${item.office_area}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Price: ${item.office_price}</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Status: </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;
  }).join('')
);
```

I had no chance to test it, so please regard it as an idea demo.
also `` outputCont.html(`${...map(...).join('')}`) `` is a bit of overuse of backticks, no need to wrap in `` `${}` `` the result of join.